# Opening the URL of a <a> link in JQuery colorbox when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need help with this JQuery code i have.. i'm still a newbie when it comes to JQuery but i have alot of codes here to test with.. you know just incase you need one so here's the code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//onload popup
$(function()
{
    $(window).bind('load', 
        function(e) 
        {
            $.colorbox({opacity:0.3, href:"ext/popup.php"}); 
        });
});

</script>
```

now this time i don't want to load the page then let the form popup.. i wan't something to click like a link.. any suggestions?

Comment: Create a link, then bind to that element rather than the window. Bind to the click event rather than the load event.

Comment: please make your question more clear its unclear

Comment: well what i would like to get is the code above is triggered when a specific page loads.. now i wan't something to click to trigger the function... sorry i'm really a newbie in JQuery.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function()
{
    $('#linkid').click(function(e) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.colorbox({opacity:0.3, href: this.href}); 
        });
});
```

And create a link like this

```
<a href="ext/popup.php" id="linkid">click me</a>
```

---

**Update**

If you want to apply this logic to multiple links you should use a class instead of an id

```
<a href="ext/popup.php" class="colorbox">click me</a>
```

and for the jquery target them with

```
$('.colorbox').click(...)
```

---

**Comment**

A generic comment on your code, you do not need to use `$(function(){..})` and `$(window).bind('load'`.
The first part binds an event on the DOM ready. and the second on the DOM load.
Since the `load` will always come ***after*** the `ready` event you can directly do

```
$(window).load(function(){...});
```

But the load should only be used when you need the sub-elements to have been completely loaded before running your code (*usually images*).
read: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Gaby uhm your answer works well.. but what if i have alot of links not just one but 3? i tried it but only 1 works.. the rest does'nt

Comment: then you should use a class instead of an id.. Added update at the middle of the answer..

Comment: oh man you're a genius... that worked well hahah i really should be learning JQuery by now i'm a bit interested in it :) thanks again Gaby

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a#yourLinkId').click(function(e){
  // prevents default behaviour
  e.preventDefault();

  // your stuff
  $.colorbox({opacity:0.3, href:"ext/popup.php"}); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

No problem. You can ask any question about JQuery here in Stackoverflow and we try to help.

About your question. I think you want to use JQuery to load the page inside the [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) instead of the default action which is loading the URL in the main window.

You need to do two things:

1. Bind an event handler to all the anchor tags (`<a>`) so whenever they are clicked your event is run.
2. Prevent the default event handler from openning the URL (preventDefault)

You can bind your event to all anchor tags like this:

```
//for all links that exist on this page up to when this line is executed
$("a").click(function(){...});
```

But I suggest binding your events using the `on()` button. That way all `<a>` tags will run this event handler even if they are created **after** your event binding code is run.

```
//for all links that are created on this page even after this lines of code is executed
$("a").on( "click", function(){...});
```

For preventing the default action (browsing to the page), you simply use the [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method:

```
//assuming event argument is called e
e.preventDefault();
```

Having said that, your code will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//this will run when the current document is loaded
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //$(this).attr("href") contains the href attribute of the <a> tag
        $.colorbox({opacity:0.3, href:$(this).attr("href")});
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: the syntax you provided is the same as the `.click()`, the elements must exist. To make it work as live/delegate did you need to bind to a container of the elements.. To mimic the `live` directlye you need to do `$(document).on('click','a',function(e){...});`